# How to phrase "If I had to choose..."?

Tags: translation

Often in English when we decide between options that all seem favorable, we'll say:

> "I like them all, but if I had to choose, I'd go with that one!"

What is the Chinese equivalent of "if I had to choose" ? It does not need to be a direct translation, just whatever you would use in that scenario.

Comment: try iciba with "if I had to":1.

If I had to choose between fish and chicken I'd prefer the former, ie fish.

若让我在鱼和鸡之间选择其一,我要前者(即鱼). This may suggest 若让我选择... or 让我选择的话。。。

Comment: -:) I presume you are talking about boyfriends?

Comment: @Pedroski hahaha that's a good point! (but why do I have to choose? :P )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“（如果）非要我选的话”

> 这些我都喜欢，非要我选的话，我要那一个！

Comment: Seem like it is very common to omit '不可' in sentences like "非要我选(不可)的话"

Comment: "（如果）一定要选的话" works too

Answer (score 2):

You can say '如果我不得不选一个' or '如果非要让我选一个' For example, 我喜欢足球，也喜欢篮球，如果非要让我选一个的话，我还是去踢足球吧。